# Help: infinite sum for matrices

Tags: matrices, power-series

Suppose $G$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

Can someone show me how you can carry

$$I + G x^{-1} + G^2 x^{-2} + G^3 x^{-3} + G ^4 x^{-4} + \cdots$$

to

$$(xI - G)^{-1}x$$

without having to "divide" over another matrix thereby performing an illegal operation?

Comment: Verify that multiplying everything by $(xI-G)x^{-1}$ gives you the identity matrix (for $x$ sufficiently small).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:  look again carefully, my friend; $x$ *sufficiently large* is what works here, since $x^{-1}G$ is the "person of interest", as the detectives say. See my answer below. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that, for *all* $x \ne 0$,

$xI - G = x(I - x^{-1}G), \tag{1}$

whence

$(xI - G)^{-1}x = (x(I - x^{-1}G))^{-1}x = (I - x^{-1}G)^{-1}x^{-1}x = (I - x^{-1}G)^{-1}. \tag{2}$

To make further progress, and connect this equation with the power series

$I + x^{-1}G + x^{-2}G^2 + x^{-3}G^3 + x^{-4}G^4 + \ldots \tag{3}$

we need some hypothesis which ensures (3) is a meaningful expression, i.e., the series converges.  This need may be met if we assume $\vert x \vert > \Vert G \Vert$, for then $\Vert x^{-1}G \Vert = \vert x^{-1} \vert \Vert G \Vert  = \vert x \vert^{-1} \Vert G \Vert < 1$; thus, in the usual manner, we write

$(I - x^{-1}G)\sum_0^m (x^{-1}G)^i = I - (x^{-1}G)^{m + 1}; \tag{4}$

with $\Vert x^{-1} G \Vert < 1$, we see that

$\Vert (x^{-1}G)^{m + 1} \Vert \le \Vert x^{-1} G \Vert^{m + 1} \to 0 \tag{5}$

as $m \to \infty$; this in turn implies the series (3) converges, since it is majorized in norm by the geometric series $\sum_0^\infty \Vert x^{-1}G \Vert^i$, and that
(4) in the limit becomes

$(I - x^{-1}G)\sum_0^ \infty(x^{-1}G)^i = I. \tag{6}$

(6) shows that

$(I - x^{-1}G)^{-1} = \sum_0^ \infty(x^{-1}G)^i, \tag{7}$

and combining this with (2) yields

$(xI - G)^{-1}x = \sum_0^ \infty(x^{-1}G)^i, \tag{8}$

as per request.

***Note Added Saturday 14 February 2015 11:19 PM PST:***  The clause "majorized in norm by the geometric series $\sum_0^\infty \Vert x^{-1}G \Vert^i$" which I used in the above, apparently, according to the comment of Math Newb (see below), could use further explication.  So here goes:  consider the sequence of partial sums

$S_m = \sum_0^m (x^{-1}G)^i; \tag{9}$

for $n > m$ we have

$S_n - S_m = \sum_{m + 1}^n  (x^{-1}G)^i, \tag{10}$

thus

$\Vert S_n - S_m \Vert = \Vert \sum_{m + 1}^n  (x^{-1}G)^i \Vert, \tag{11}$

and so, by the triangle inequality and $\Vert XY \Vert \le \Vert X \Vert \Vert Y \Vert$ for matrices $X$ and $Y$,

$\Vert S_n - S_m \Vert \le \sum_{m + 1}^n  \Vert(x^{-1}G)^i \Vert \le  \sum_{m + 1}^n  \Vert(x^{-1}G) \Vert^i$
$= \Vert x^{-1}G \Vert^{m + 1} \sum_0^{n - m -1} \Vert x^{-1} G\Vert^i. \tag{12}$

The sum on the right is geometric, with ratio $\Vert x^{-1} G \Vert < 1$; it increases monotoically as $n - m - 1$ grows, being entirely comprised of positive terms.  Thus, as is well-known, we have

$\sum_0^{n - m -1} \Vert x^{-1} G\Vert^i < \sum_0^\infty \Vert x^{-1} G\Vert^i = \dfrac{1}{1 - \Vert x^{-1} G \Vert}, \tag{13}$

and it then follows that

$\Vert S_n - S_m \Vert < \dfrac{ \Vert x^{-1}G \Vert^{m + 1}}{1 - \Vert x^{-1} G \Vert} \tag{14}$

for any $m$ independently of $n > m$.  This shows that the sequence $S_m$ is Cauchy and hence converges, from which the rest of my argument follows.  This note is basically an expansive expansion of the definition of the phrase "*majorized in norm*"; and, hoping the bots and other censors sleep at this late hour, I add I truly hope this helps the OP decipher my words.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: hello sir what do you mean by "majorized in norm"

Comment: Well, ***sir***, (I like that, "***sir***" is good!) I mean *precisely* that $\Vert \sum (x^{-1}G)^i \Vert \le \sum \Vert x^{-1}G \Vert^i$; the norm is bounded (*majorized*) by a geometric series.  Clear enough?  Let me know!  More Cheers!

Comment: @MathNewb:  ***Sir!*** I added a few words in my answer to further explicate this matter.  Best.